# MySQL "LOAD DATA INFILE" is importing unquoted "NULL" string as `NULL`

Tags: mysql, csv, null

I'm using MySQL 5.7.35. If I use the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command on a CSV file with NULL as an unquoted string value in the CSV file, the value is imported as `NULL` in MySQL.

For example, if I import a CSV file with the following content:

```
record_number,a,b,c,d,e,f
1,1,2,3,4,5,6
2,NULL,null,Null,nUlL,,"NULL"
```

The imported table will have the following values:

```
+---------------+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| record_number | a    | b      | c      | d      | e      | f      |
+---------------+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|             1 | 1    | 2      | 3      | 4      | 5      | 6      |
|             2 | NULL | "null" | "Null" | "nUlL" | ""     | "NULL" |
+---------------+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Is there any way to force column a, record 2, to be imported as a string without modifying the CSV file?

**Update**

@Barmar Pointed out that there's a paragraph in the MySQL documentation on this behavior [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html):

> If FIELDS ENCLOSED BY is not empty, a field containing the literal
> word NULL as its value is read as a NULL value. This differs from the
> word NULL enclosed within FIELDS ENCLOSED BY characters, which is read
> as the string 'NULL'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html):

> If `FIELDS ENCLOSED BY` is not empty, a field containing the literal word `NULL` as its value is read as a `NULL` value. This differs from the word `NULL` enclosed within `FIELDS ENCLOSED BY` characters, which is read as the string `'NULL'`.

So you need to specify the quoting character with something like `FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"'` and then write `"NULL"` in the CSV file.

You could check for a NULL value in your code and convert it to a string.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
  INTO TABLE t1
  (record_number, @a, @b, @c, @d, @e, @f)
  SET a = IFNULL(@a, 'NULL'),
      b = IFNULL(@b, 'NULL'),
      c = IFNULL(@c, 'NULL'),
      d = IFNULL(@d, 'NULL'),
      e = IFNULL(@e, 'NULL'),
      f = IFNULL(@f, 'NULL')
```

However, this can't distinguish between an intentional `NULL` written as `\N` and MySQL treating `NULL` as `NULL.`

Comment: Ah, I see. So there's no way to import NULL as a string short of enclosing it in whatever character sequence is specified using the `FIELDS ENCLOSED BY` clause? If so, that's really disappointing. I often times don't have control over the CSV files which are being imported.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you can check for it using user variables.

Comment: You're updated suggested is looking like a good candidate solution. The only potential problem is if a field contained `\N` and it was converted to `"NULL"`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's a complete solution.